# Style an element when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

Even before I click the button the h1 tagged element comes yellow what should I do to fix it? Just want to make them yellow when I click on the button.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>  

<h1>Hello</h1>

<h2>World</h2>

<h1>test</h1>


<button id="button">click</button>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("button");

    x.addEventListener("onclick",change());

    function change(){
        var myNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

        for (var i = 0; i < myNodes.length ; i++) {
            myNodes[i].style.backgroundColor  = "yellow";
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues in your `js` snippet first in `x.addEventListener("onclick",change());`

the event should be `click` instead of onclick,secondly `change()` will immediately call the function , but `x.addEventListener("click",change)` will trigger the function only when it is clicked

```js
var x = document.getElementById("button");

x.addEventListener("click", change);

function change() {
  var myNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

  for (var i = 0; i < myNodes.length; i++) {
    myNodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello </h1>

<h2>World</h2>

<h1>test</h1>


<button id="button">click</button>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. How can I learn details like that? Is there a page that I can read and practice?

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListner` accepts a function, rather than the return value to a function. Your `change()` is calling the function `change`, and the return value is being passed to `addEventListener`.

```
<script>
        const button = document.getElementById("button");
    
        button.addEventListener("click", change);
    
        function change(){
            const myNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
            for (let i = 0; i < myNodes.length ; i++) {
                myNodes[i].style.backgroundColor  = "yellow";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

There are easier and more graceful ways of accomplishing this, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Code only answers aren't very useful without an explanation of what was changed and why

Comment: Especially when there's a linked duplicate that does a better job

Comment: @charlietfl its not because addeventlistner fires on pageload

Comment: It's not me that needs the explanation ... it's anyone that reads the answer